Is there a way to generate the authorization url for the importdata function to run?
I have a script set up to generate a spreadsheet we use when a new file is created in a particular folder.  It uses the importdata() function in google sheets.
Recently google sheets updated their permissions (I was wondering when this was going to happen) to disallow the importdata() function until it's authorized (the importdata function we use has URL parameters).  The problem is that the initial use of the spreadsheet is frequently via the mobile app and the authorization button doesn't show for the mobile user to authorize the app.
To be clear:

this button that is displayed on the desktop only and my issue is that the first use is often via mobile.
It is authorizing the Spreadsheet to send/receive data and NOT the underlying apps script.  Even if the underlying apps script has the ability to send/receive, the spreadsheet will not allow the importdata() function to work (particularly if it has URL parameters)

The URL that this authorization button posts to is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/{spreadsheetID}/externaldata/allowexternalurlaccess?token={token}&includes_info_params=true&usp=drive_fs&cros_files=false
I have tried generating this URL in apps script for the user to click on but it needs to be a post and not a get request.  A get request to the URL returns a 404 error.
This issue should be easily duplicated by opening a new google sheet and adding the importdata() function to a cell with a URL with URL parameters.

Have you confirmed post works?

Try the externaldata/allowexternalurlaccess endpoint. See Allowing Access by IMPORTHTML, IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTXML, and IMPORTRANGE on Google Spreadsheet with Google Apps Script.

The problem is that the initial use of the spreadsheet is frequently via the mobile app and the authorization button doesn't show for the mobile user to authorize the app. is addressed by @TheMaster in their answer to this Stack Overflow post stating that Buttons/Menu items don't work.

@doubleunary My bad. Though the reason why I said that is because of the statement I've highlighted and this button that is displayed on the desktop only and my issue is that the first use is often via mobile. Do you think it's better to just delete that now or wait until the poster responds?

@doubleunary Isn't that the exact endpoint  that OP already posted in their question? @Rob, What is the question? How to execute post from mobile app? Or How to use Apps script to post? Or something else?

I've read the question again. The "first use is often via mobile" bit causes an issue that's different from what I though initially. Rob, please add a [mre].
